# Assertion failed -> Python Flask App using matplotlib, pyplot and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, flask, assertion

I'm getting a weird error running my Flask Python App. I'm just trying to save a png image of the soundwaves of a wave file. I've tried the code with a small python program, which worked perfectly. But now I tried to implement it into a bigger flask app, there appears a very weird error.

The function should be saving a png image of a wave file, that was just uploaded and saved on the server. The image is actually saved, so the function must be running all the way to the end, but afterwards I get a big error (look below), python crashes and also the flask server crashes.

I hope you can help.

**The function which is causing the error is the following:**

```
    signal = spf.readframes(-1)
    signal = np.fromstring(signal, "Int16")
    fs = spf.getframerate()

    # If Stereo
    if spf.getnchannels() == 2:
        print("Just mono files")
        sys.exit(0)

    Time = np.linspace(0, len(signal) / fs, num=len(signal))

    plt.figure(1)
    plt.title("Signal Wave...")
    plt.plot(Time, signal)
    plt.savefig('foo.png')
```

**Error Message:**

```
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jun/2020 07:27:57] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jun/2020 07:27:58] "GET /upload HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2020-06-05 07:28:06.440 Python[64276:1020963] WARNING: NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread! This will throw an exception in the future. Called from (
    0   AppKit                              0x00007fff31ddb289 -[NSWindow(NSWindow_Theme) _postWindowNeedsToResetDragMarginsUnlessPostingDisabled] + 371
    1   AppKit                              0x00007fff31dc2cb2 -[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 1416
    2   AppKit                              0x00007fff31dc2723 -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 42
    3   _macosx.cpython-38-darwin.so        0x000000011486d7c0 -[Window initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:withManager:] + 80
    4   _macosx.cpython-38-darwin.so        0x0000000114870ccf FigureManager_init + 319
    5   Python                              0x000000010d683bdc wrap_init + 12
    6   Python                              0x000000010d635379 wrapperdescr_call + 121
    7   Python                              0x000000010d62c565 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 373
    8   Python                              0x000000010d6faca5 call_function + 533
    9   Python                              0x000000010d6f7aae _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25678
    10  Python                              0x000000010d62ceb0 function_code_fastcall + 128
    11  Python                              0x000000010d62c3b7 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 247
    12  Python                              0x000000010d62d9bf _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 143
    13  Python                              0x000000010d683b21 slot_tp_init + 145
    14  Python                              0x000000010d67eff9 type_call + 297
    15  Python                              0x000000010d62c565 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 373
    16  Python                              0x000000010d6faca5 call_function + 533
    17  Python                              0x000000010d6f7aae _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25678
    18  Python                              0x000000010d62ceb0 function_code_fastcall + 128
    19  Python                              0x000000010d62f57a method_vectorcall + 170
    20  Python                              0x000000010d6fac4c call_function + 444
    21  Python                              0x000000010d6f7aae _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25678
    22  Python                              0x000000010d6fba94 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2804
    23  Python                              0x000000010d62d04e _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 270
    24  Python                              0x000000010d62f65c method_vectorcall + 396
    25  Python                              0x000000010d62c88d PyVectorcall_Call + 109
    26  Python                              0x000000010d6f7fb8 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 26968
    27  Python                              0x000000010d6fba94 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2804
    28  Python                              0x000000010d62d04e _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 270
    29  Python                              0x000000010d6fac4c call_function + 444
    30  Python                              0x000000010d6f7aae _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25678
    31  Python                              0x000000010d62ceb0 function_code_fastcall + 128
    32  Python                              0x000000010d62c88d PyVectorcall_Call + 109
    33  Python                              0x000000010d6f7fb8 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 26968
    34  Python                              0x000000010d62ceb0 function_code_fastcall + 128
    35  Python                              0x000000010d6fac4c call_function + 444
    36  Python                              0x000000010d6f7a8a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25642
    37  Python                              0x000000010d62ceb0 function_code_fastcall + 128
    38  Python                              0x000000010d6fac4c call_function + 444
    39  Python                              0x000000010d6f7a8a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25642
    40  Python                              0x000000010d62ceb0 function_code_fastcall + 128
    41  Python                              0x000000010d6fac4c call_function + 444
    42  Python                              0x000000010d6f7a8a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25642
    43  Python                              0x000000010d62ceb0 function_code_fastcall + 128
    44  Python                              0x000000010d62c3b7 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 247
    45  Python                              0x000000010d62d9bf _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 143
    46  Python                              0x000000010d682496 slot_tp_call + 150
    47  Python                              0x000000010d62c565 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 373
    48  Python                              0x000000010d6faca5 call_function + 533
    49  Python                              0x000000010d6f7aae _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25678
    50  Python                              0x000000010d62ceb0 function_code_fastcall + 128
    51  Python                              0x000000010d62c3b7 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 247
    52  Python                              0x000000010d62d9bf _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 143
    53  Python                              0x000000010d682496 slot_tp_call + 150
    54  Python                              0x000000010d62c565 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 373
    55  Python                              0x000000010d6faca5 call_function + 533
    56  Python                              0x000000010d6f7aae _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25678
    57  Python                              0x000000010d63d22e gen_send_ex + 206
    58  Python                              0x000000010d6f720f _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 23471
    59  Python                              0x000000010d6fba94 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2804
    60  Python                              0x000000010d62d04e _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 270
    61  Python                              0x000000010d6fac4c call_function + 444
    62  Python                              0x000000010d6f7b45 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25829
    63  Python                              0x000000010d6fba94 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2804
    64  Python                              0x000000010d62d04e _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 270
    65  Python                              0x000000010d6fac4c call_function + 444
    66  Python                              0x000000010d6f7a8a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25642
    67  Python                              0x000000010d62ceb0 function_code_fastcall + 128
    68  Python                              0x000000010d6fac4c call_function + 444
    69  Python                              0x000000010d6f7a8a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25642
    70  Python                              0x000000010d62ceb0 function_code_fastcall + 128
    71  Python                              0x000000010d6fac4c call_function + 444
    72  Python                              0x000000010d6f7aae _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25678
    73  Python                              0x000000010d62ceb0 function_code_fastcall + 128
    74  Python                              0x000000010d6fac4c call_function + 444
    75  Python                              0x000000010d6f7a8a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25642
    76  Python                              0x000000010d62ceb0 function_code_fastcall + 128
    77  Python                              0x000000010d62c3b7 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 247
    78  Python                              0x000000010d62d9bf _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 143
    79  Python                              0x000000010d683b21 slot_tp_init + 145
    80  Python                              0x000000010d67eff9 type_call + 297
    81  Python                              0x000000010d62c565 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 373
    82  Python                              0x000000010d6faca5 call_function + 533
    83  Python                              0x000000010d6f7aae _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25678
    84  Python                              0x000000010d62ceb0 function_code_fastcall + 128
    85  Python                              0x000000010d6fac4c call_function + 444
    86  Python                              0x000000010d6f7a8a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25642
    87  Python                              0x000000010d62ceb0 function_code_fastcall + 128
    88  Python                              0x000000010d62f65c method_vectorcall + 396
    89  Python                              0x000000010d62c88d PyVectorcall_Call + 109
    90  Python                              0x000000010d6f7fb8 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 26968
    91  Python                              0x000000010d62ceb0 function_code_fastcall + 128
    92  Python                              0x000000010d6fac4c call_function + 444
    93  Python                              0x000000010d6f7a8a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25642
    94  Python                              0x000000010d62ceb0 function_code_fastcall + 128
    95  Python                              0x000000010d6fac4c call_function + 444
    96  Python                              0x000000010d6f7a8a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25642
    97  Python                              0x000000010d62ceb0 function_code_fastcall + 128
    98  Python                              0x000000010d62f5bb method_vectorcall + 235
    99  Python                              0x000000010d62c88d PyVectorcall_Call + 109
    100 Python                              0x000000010d79a79a t_bootstrap + 74
    101 Python                              0x000000010d74da89 pythread_wrapper + 25
    102 libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6ec7b109 _pthread_start + 148
    103 libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6ec76b8b thread_start + 15
)
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jun/2020 07:28:06] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Assertion failed: (NSViewIsCurrentlyBuildingLayerTreeForDisplay() != currentlyBuildingLayerTree), function NSViewSetCurrentlyBuildingLayerTreeForDisplay, file /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-1894.40.150/AppKit.subproj/NSView.m, line 13568.
```

Comment: Please show the entire function. The stack trace suggests that there's code that assumes it has a local UI available.

Comment: It seems that I had to insert the following code to make the error stop."import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
# If you do the import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, do it here"

Comment: Hah. I'd completely forgotten about the bit of magic.